# How can I read values' names and data from the registry?

Tags: delphi, registry, delphi-7

I have stored a list of items from gridView into the registry as below:

```
frmPOSConfigSet.tblCatItems.First;  
while not frmPOSConfigSet.tblCatItems.Eof do
begin  
  RegItemSetting.WriteString('stk Group\Candy',
    frmPOSConfigSet.tblCatItemsCODE.Text,
    frmPOSConfigSet.tblCatItemsSPHOTO.Text);
  frmPOSConfigSet.tblCatItems.Next;  
end;
```

In Registry Editor, I have this:

stk Group
- Candy
  -> YUPI_GUM_HB  , c:\Users\chai\Pictures\POS Item Images\image1.jpg
  -> YUPI_GUM_SBKISS  , c:\Users\chai\Pictures\POS Item Images\image2.jpg

After I close the form and open it again, all values in gridView are gone. How can I retrieve the ident (eg. YUPI_GUM_HB) and its value (eg.c:\Users\chai\Pictures\POS Item Images\image1.jpg) from the registry and put it in the gridView when I load the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't quite look like you're using `TRegistry` (too many parameters to `WriteString`), but if you were, you could use it to get everything back out of the registry. I suspect you're stuck because you want to call [`ReadString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Registry.TRegistry.ReadString), but you don't know the registry values' names, so you don't know what to pass into `ReadString`.

You can get a list of all the values' names by calling [`GetValueNames`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Registry.TRegistry.GetValueNames). Pass it a `TStringList` (or any other `TStrings` descendant), and that method will fill the list with all the value names.

```
var
  Names: TStrings;
  Name, Data: string;
  i: Integer;
begin
  RegItemSetting.OpenKeyReadOnly('stk Group\Candy');
  Names := TStringList.Create;
  try
    RegItemSetting.GetValueNames(Names);
    for i := 0 to Pred(Names.Count) do begin
      Name := Names[i];
      Data := RegItemSetting.ReadString(Name);
    end;
  finally
    Names.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I don't know what gridView is, so I cannot answer that question. You say the stuff you stored in the registry came from gridView, so how did you get it into gridView in the first place?

Comment: i stored and retrieve data from gridView to registry through the dataset.

Comment: So it's a data-aware grid control? Then, to get it into the grid, put the stuff into a dataset. I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: The gridView is TwwwDBGrid and the dataset is TClientDataSet, it link with each other. So when i append the data to dataset, it will automatic show the data in gridView.